# FreePascal: How to use GetEnvironmentVariable in non-latin Windows?

Tags: windows, encoding, lazarus, freepascal

I've been writing some code using Lazarus 1.6.4 and FPC 3.0.2 to get USERNAME in Windows and USER in Linux. To achieve this I used SysUtils.GetEnvironmentVariable function. In Linux it works perfect, but in Windows it returns something corrupted that looks like UTF8 string opened in wrong encoding. My USERNAME in Windows has Cyrillic symbols so instead of the actual name GetEnvironmentVariable returns `????????` but it should be `Пользователь`.
Here my code:

```
function GetUserName: string;
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
const
  envVar = 'USERNAME';
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF UNIX}
  envVar = 'USER';
{$ENDIF}
begin
  Result := SysUtils.GetEnvironmentVariable(envVar);
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  { TODO : BUG: Does not work correct for non-latin strings }
  Result := LazUTF8.UTF8ToWinCP(Result)
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

And it returns corrupted strings when it contains non-latain symbols inside.

How can I GetEnvironmentVariable in correct encoding in Windows OS?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik in 3.0+ getenvironmentvariable is overloaded for unicodestring on windows, and that uses the -W variant.

```
var res,tag : unicodestring;

begin
  tag:='HOME';
  res:=getenvironmentvariable(tag);
end;
```

Just

```
  getenvironmentstring (unicodestring('whatever'));
```

might also work, but make sure you either set utf8 as default encoding, or assign the result to an unicodestring.

Answer (score -1):

After a day run I found the solution that work for me. You should use Unicode version of `SysUtils.GetEnvironmentVariable` and convert the result to the Windows current code page. Here the code below:

```
uses
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  LazUTF8
  {$ENDIF}
  ;

function GetUserName: string;
const
  envVar: UnicodeString =
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  'USERNAME'
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF UNIX}
  'USER'
{$ENDIF};
begin
  // USE Unicode String Version only!
  Result := SysUtils.GetEnvironmentVariable(envVar);
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  Result := LazUTF8.UTF8ToWinCP(Result)
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

**UPDATE 01.12.2017**
My Solution depends on ENV as David mentioned in comments. During the discussion I found more reliable solution [here](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,23171.msg138057.html#msg138057). The code below:

```
function GetCurrentUserName: String;

{$IFDEF WINDOWS}
const
  MaxLen = 256;
var
  Len: DWORD;
  WS: WideString;
  Res: windows.BOOL;
{$ENDIF}
begin
  Result := '';
  {$IFDEF UNIX}
  {$IF (DEFINED(LINUX)) OR (DEFINED(FREEBSD))}
  Result := SysToUtf8(GetUserName(fpgetuid));   //GetUsername in unit Users, fpgetuid in unit BaseUnix
  {$ELSE Linux/BSD}
  Result := GetEnvironmentVariableUtf8('USER');
  {$ENDIF UNIX}
  {$ELSE}
  {$IFDEF WINDOWS}
  Len := MaxLen;
  {$IFnDEF WINCE}
  if Win32MajorVersion <= 4 then
  begin
    SetLength(Result,MaxLen);
    Res := Windows.GetuserName(@Result[1], Len);
    //writeln('GetUserNameA = ',Res);
    if Res then
    begin
      SetLength(Result,Len-1);
      Result := SysToUtf8(Result);
    end
    else SetLength(Result,0);
  end
  else
  {$ENDIF NOT WINCE}
  begin
    SetLength(WS, MaxLen-1);
    Res := Windows.GetUserNameW(@WS[1], Len);
    //writeln('GetUserNameW = ',Res);
    if Res then
    begin
      SetLength(WS, Len - 1);
      Result := Utf16ToUtf8(WS);
    end
    else SetLength(Result,0);
  end;
  {$ENDIF WINDOWS}
  {$ENDIF UNIX}
end;
```

Comment: This isn't how to get the username on Windows and further you do not want to use ANSI encoding on Windows.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Please explain more detailed. And what would you suggest?

Comment: You don't want to use ANSI encoding ever because it can only encode a limited set of characters. And to get the current user name you use a Win32 API function that provides that service. For instance `GetUserName`. Perhaps the Lazarus or FPC RTL wraps that already, I don't know.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Lazarus does not have it.`GetUserName` function listed only in UNIX related context. I don't understand why should I use more complicated  solution when my solution does the work and produces the correct output?

Comment: Obviously you can do what you like. But it won't work with characters outside your locale, and there's no guarantee at all that the environment variable will even exist. And `GetUserName` will be available in the windows header translation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I found the solution with windows.GetName here http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,23171.msg138057.html#msg138057 but what the reason to use this when results the same?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks. I didn't mention that ENV can be changed... GetUserName if more reliable.

Comment: The text encoding issue can be fixed by not converting to ANSI. But the issue with environment vars is real. Windows is just different from Unix. It tends to prefer API functions more than Unix does.